# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component implemented using HOOK

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code on React for user authentication. NOTE: RUNNING IN EXPO.

```
function App(){
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  if (user){  
      return <Dashboard user={user} />
    }
    return <Authentication login={user => setUser(user)}/>;


}
export default App;
```

User login function:

```
  userLogin = (email, password) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(error => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              console.warn('Invalid email address format.');
              break;
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
            case 'auth/wrong-password':
              console.warn('Invalid email address or password');
              break;
            default:
              console.warn('Check your internet connection');
          }
          resolve(null);
        }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          resolve(user);
        }
      });
    })
  };
```

Once successfully logged in, I am diverted to Dashboard however I received this warning. I've tried using useEffect but I'm still having the same warning.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method.
```

Comment: can you provide the code for Authentication component?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I have edited my post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think you edited your question... the problem is likely in the Authentication component

Comment: Please check the login code. Thanks.

Comment: you need make the state like global state

Comment: How? Please help me out?

Comment: @Gio_Serg check this https://dev.to/rahmanfadhil/global-state-with-react-hooks-15fm this works like redux

Answer (score 0):

You must call `login` prop after promise resolves, here's minimal example

```js
const { useState } = React

function Dashboard () {
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>
}

function Authentication ({ login }) {
  const userLogin = (username, password) => {
    const query = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true)
      }, 1000)
    })
    
    query.then(login)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Authentication</h1>
      <button onClick={userLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function App(){
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  if (user){  
    return <Dashboard user={user} />
  }
  return <Authentication login={user => setUser(user)}/>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It just set a delay on login process, i think.

Comment: it simulates your firebase request